# Using a scheduled function variable

Tags: python, serial-port, scheduler

I'm coding a script that uses a defined function scheduled to run every X seconds. The scheduled function works fine, the problem is that I'm not able to use it downstream, specifically in adding that variable `g` to a list called `numlist`. How can I do it?

Code used:

```
import serial
import numpy as np
import time
from random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import schedule

ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 115200)

def read_serial_port():
    global g
    ser.flushInput()
    x = ser.readline().decode("utf_8").rstrip('\n\r')
    g=float(x)
    print(g)

rate_in_seconds = 0.5
schedule.every(rate_in_seconds).seconds.do(read_serial_port)

numlist = [0]

start_time = int(round(time.time()))
timelist = [start_time]

speed = []

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

    for x in range(0, 10):
        elapsed_time = int(round(time.time() - start_time))
        numlist.append(g)
        print(numlist[-1])
    # timelist.append(elapsed_time)
        timelist.append(int(round(time.time())))

        x = numlist[-1]
        y = numlist[len(numlist)-2]
        t1 = timelist[-1]
        t2 = timelist[len(timelist)-2]

    # speed calculation
        kmh = abs((x-y)/(t2-t1))*3.6
        speed.append(kmh)

    # brake distance calculation
        d = (kmh ** 2)/(250*0.8)
        print('speed', speed[-1], 'km/h')
        print('total distance:', numlist[-1], 'm')
        print('breaking distance:', d, 'm')

        if d >= numlist[-1]:
            print('run!')
            print('\n')


#plt.plot(speed)
#plt.show()
```

When I run it, it keeps saying that variable `g` does not exist:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtWvm.png)

Thanks

Comment: i think the problem is that the `schedule` module runs the function in a way it doesn't let `g` be defined properly as a `global` variable. Which is not a good practice (using `global` variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the variable **g** outside of **read_serial_port()** function.
Such as -

```
g = None  # or something else

def read_serial_port():
    global g    # global g here actually means, it is pointing to the variable out of the function and the manipulation will impact on g variable declared outside of the function 
    ser.flushInput()
    x = ser.readline().decode("utf_8").rstrip('\n\r')
    g=float(x)
    print(g)
```

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. Having a global variable works.

Comment: Nice to know. Please accept the answer as it's working :)